# Cancel request at any time during a flow

Tags: mobile, payment, money

I am currently designing a payment flow for a mobile app. The flow is divided in 5 steps :

1. Choose account
2. Scan QR Code
3. Enter amount + Memo
4. Fees
5. Review & send

While I was designing it, I told myself, what if the user wants to cancel everything and go back to the Dashboard.
As of today, I have no Cancel button on my flow but go back buttons obviously.

What do you think about it ? Should I add a Cancel button, or I should let the user close the app and re-open it?

Thanks

Comment: What about a "Start Over" button? Closing an app and reopening can be dangerous to design for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alan. Finally, I added 2 buttons ( Cancel & Next in the Navigation view ). The main problem is that they can't go back to the previous step. This is also a bit confusing. 
Here's a before/after screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/TrQG5

Answer (score 1):

> **Fundamental Usability Heuristic - "Support Undo and Redo"**
>
> *Users often choose system functions by mistake and will need a clearly marked "emergency exit" to leave the unwanted state without having to go through an extended dialogue. Support undo and redo.*
>
> -- Nielsen Norman Group
>
> https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

Any user who wants to cancel out, for whatever reason, and discovers after looking around that the only option is to close and restart, will likely consider this a PITA and a bad experience.

Provide a simple 'Cancel' option in a secondary action area, out of reach of accidental taps.

Comment: I definitely agree with you. Please find a Before/After screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/TrQG5